# How to Add New Freehand Shapes and Data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS. Can anyone either direct me to a good tutorial or explain? I want to draw freehand new shape layers on to Google Earth to map vegetation types and embedded data for each feature. I am able to draw a shapes as a layer on the map, but I don't understand if or  how to customise the attribute table for that layer and every time I try to draw a new shape for that layer it comes up with window saying id. or should I be using one of the different database functions?

Thanks for your time.

paddy

Answer (score 1):

Please read the manual: http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#creating-a-new-vector-layer

You need to add create the attribute fields as shown in

[image]